# How can I get featured media when selecting only few fields from WordPress REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Generally to get the featured media we would do something like this with the WordPress REST API: https://test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed

However this will return all the fields. I only want to return few fields so I've modified my URL like this:

[https://test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields[]=id&_fields[]=title&_fields[]=categories&_fields[]=_embedded](https://test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields%5B%5D=id&_fields%5B%5D=title&_fields%5B%5D=categories&_fields%5B%5D=_embedded)

Because _embedded is a property that is returned in the above posts but it does not return the featured media so then I also tried to use this URL:

[https://test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields[]=id&_fields[]=title&_fields[]=categories&_embed](https://test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields%5B%5D=id&_fields%5B%5D=title&_fields%5B%5D=categories&_embed)

But even that is not returning me the featured media. How can I get the featured media while only selecting few fields?